# PHP connect to MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (64-bit) with PHP Version 5.3.3 configured as:

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-mysql' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--disable-pdo' '--disable-xmlreader' '--disable-xmlwriter' '--without-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-json' '--without-pspell' '--disable-wddx' '--without-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem'
```

I would like to (need to) connect to a MS SQL database on another server. I have tried using mssql_connect but get 'Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in ...'

I am using the Zend DB framework for my MySQL connections and wanted to use that, I tired `'adapter' => 'pdo_dblib'` and `'adapter' => 'pdo_mssql'` but just get errors about drivers not being installed.

In `'/usr/lib64/php/modules'` I have:

```
curl.so, dom.so, fileinfo.so, gd.so, json.so, mbstring.so, mysqli.so, mysql.so, pdo.so, pdo_sqlite.so, phar.so, sqlite3.so, wddx.so, xmlreader.so, xmlwriter.so, xsl.so, zip.so
```

Can anyone offer me some advice please? I have tried my best to find the answer which seems to be 'enable this extension'... the ones that are not there!

I have a feeling I will need to download some files using Yum and changing my repo.

Many Thanks,
David

Comment: You've basically answered your own question: you have to `yum install` the PHP extension. What's your exact problem?

Comment: Well, it looks like you didn't install the MSSQL extension.

Comment: General tip for this site: if you get an error, TELL US what the error message is. If you don't, it's like going to the doctor, saying you've got an owie, and then not saying anything else.

Comment: The PHP MSSQL needs the FreeTDS library (http://www.freetds.org/) Is this installed?